# Pig Latin syntax error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, latin

I have the following data:

```
AGE,EDU,SEX,SALARY
67,10th,Male,<=50K
17,10th,Female,<=50K
40,Assoc-voc,Male,>50K
35,Assoc-voc,Male,<=50K
57,Assoc-voc,Male,<=50K
49,Assoc-voc,Male,>50K
42,Bachelors,Male,>50K
30,Bachelors,Male,>50K
23,Bachelors,Female,<=50K
```

========================================================

my Pig Latin script is:

```
sensitive = LOAD '/mdsba' using PigStorage(',') as (AGE,EDU,SEX,SALARY);
--Filtered the data by the city
Data_filter1 = FILTER sensitive by (SALARY matches '<=50K');
Data_filter2 = FILTER sensitive by (SALARY matches '>50K');
BA= group  Data_filter1 by (EDU,SEX) ; 

BB= foreach BA generate group as EDU, COUNT (Data_filter1) as cn:int;

BC= FILTER BB by (cn == 4);

Dump BC ;
```

the error message :

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

any help please

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you are mixing an int data type with a long data type.

You need to manually convert the int to long.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [COUNT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#COUNT) return a long but you convert it to int 
Your code should look like this:

```
BB= foreach BA generate group as EDU, COUNT (Data_filter1) as cn;
```

or

```
BB= foreach BA generate group as EDU, COUNT (Data_filter1) as cn:long;
```